# Can't type inside an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I can't change or type inside an input, I have the input inside a form and it's value set to user.email, when I try to change the text it won't type

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch({type: "UPDATE_START"})
        const updatedUser = {
          userId: user._id,
          username,
          email,
        };
        try {
          const res = await axios.put("/users/"+user._id, updatedUser);
          setSuccess(true);
          dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SUCCESS", payload: res.data });
        } catch (err) {
          dispatch({type: "UPDATE_FAILURE"});
        }
      };
                
    <form className="settingsForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div class="relative w-full">
                        <div class="flex absolute
                        inset-y-0 left-0 items-center pl-3
                        pointer-events-none">
                            <EmailIcon class="w-5 h-5" />
                        </div>
                        <input type="text"
                        className="loginInput"
                        style={{ border: error ? '1px solid red' : '' }}
                        value={user.email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                    </div>
                <button
              className="loginButton"
              type="submit"
              disabled={isFetching}>
              {isFetching ? (
                    <CircularProgress size={15}/>
                ) : (
                <Typography
                variant="subtitle2"
                color="white">
                  Save Changes
                </Typography>)}
            </button>
    </form>
```

I don't what I'm missing here, and I don't want the `user.email` to be placeholder, I want to treat as a value and be changeable.

Comment: The `email` state changes, but `user.email` does not. Set the default state value to `user.email` and use the `email` state as the `value`.

Comment: THANK YOU, this should be the answer! I used "defaultValue"

Answer (score 1):

You need to put only email in the value key. Because when **setEmail** function called, it will set the value at the **email** const. so you need to pass only email const at the value key like below :

```
<input type="text"
       className="loginInput"
       style={{ border: error ? '1px solid red' : '' }}
       value={email}
       onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} 
/>
```

Comment: how to set the input to user's email? I just need the input contains the user's email, when a user clicks on the input, he/she can edit it

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` is set to set the email field to the original value when the value changes. So that's why trying to change it is not working

```
                 <input type="text"
                    className="loginInput"
                    style={{ border: error ? '1px solid red' : '' }}
                    value={user.email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
```